# How to remove class using CSS?

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to make my wordpress blog responsive for mobile devices. I was able to customize homepage in style.css, but I'm having some problems with single post page.

The problem is: I have three columns and I want to remove right and left sidebars. But they are not id like on homepage, but classes.

Single post page has one id (`#postcolumn`) with 3 classes: `.leftsidebar`, `.postzone` and `.rightsidebar`. How do I remove `.leftsidebar` and `.rightsidebar`?

Here is my code for homepage, which is working great...

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #wrapper, #header, #column {
        width:400px;
    }

    #middlecolumn, #rightcolumn, #header, #footer {
        display:none
    }
}
```

Comment: A _pound_ / _sharp_ `#` indicates an **id** as your `#header` shows. A _class_ is indicated by a _dot_ `.` as in `.sidebar` or `div.sidebar`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your HTML markup for your single post page looks something like the following:

```
<div id="postcolumn">
  <div class="leftsidebar">
    // something
  </div>
  <div class="postzone">
    // something
  </div>
  <div class="rightsidebar">
    // something
  </div>
</div>
```

Applying the same logic as your home page, the CSS would look like:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    #wrapper, #header, #column {
        width:400px;
    }

    #middlecolumn, #rightcolumn, #header, #footer, #postcolumn .leftsidebar, #postcolumn .rightsidebar {
        display:none
    }
}
```